# ImportError: cannot import name 'AdultDataset' from 'dataset'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch

Please I am working on AdultDataset for a classification task

I found out: `from dataset import AdultDataset`

is giving the error below:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AdultDataset' from 'dataset'
```

## Import Relevant Libraries

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import torch
import torch.nn as nn

import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


from dataset import AdultDataset
```

So when I am trying to create a 3 layer Feed Forward Neural network
using pytorch that takes as input the a dataset entries and classifies
if the individuals gains more or less than 50K (i.e., the fnlwgt label)

starting with the code below I get an error

```
train_dataset = AdultDataset(X_train, y_train)
test_dataset = AdultDataset(X_test, y_test)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-4ab31bdb6258> in <module>
      1 # Using norm_D01
      2 
----> 3 train_dataset = AdultDataset(X_train, y_train)
      4 test_dataset = AdultDataset(X_test, y_test)
      5 

NameError: name 'AdultDataset' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem can be fixed like this:

```
from aif360.datasets import AdultDataset
```

Maybe you are using an old guide?